# WebClient Logging Inbound and Outbound Traffice Problem

Tags: java, http, spring-webclient

I have a problem with WebClient. I am using [Http Interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webflux-http-interface-client.html) with WebClient and I must log inbound/outbound traffic into database. I wrote this log filter but some services throw `NullPointerException`. I tried `subscribe` instead of `block` bot not working. I have tried many more things but I cannot solve this problem. Can you help me?

Spring boot version: 3.1.1

Here is my filter;

```java
public ExchangeFilterFunction logFilter() {

    return (request, next) ->
        next.exchange(request)
            .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .doOnNext(
                clientResponse -> {
                  clientResponse
                      .bodyToMono(String.class)
                      .doOnNext(
                          clientResponseAsString -> {
                            try {
                              // save request and response to database
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                              log.error(
                                  "Something went wrong in saveOutboundLog method", e.getCause());
                            }
                          })
                      .block();
                });
  }
```

My client bean;

```java
@Bean
public BaseApiClient client(HttpClient httpClient) {
    final var webClient =
        WebClient.builder()
            .codecs(
                clientCodecConfigurer ->
                    clientCodecConfigurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(32 * 1024 * 1024))
            .baseUrl(clientProperties.getBaseUrl())
            .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
            .filter(logFilter())
            .build();
    final var factory =
        HttpServiceProxyFactory.builder(WebClientAdapter.forClient(webClient))
            .blockTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .build();
    return factory.createClient(MyClient.class);
  }
```

Comment: I worked in this once and it's not really an easy answer in WebFlux. You would have to read the entire response, write it to the DB, then create a new Flux to pass along. Do you know the response will fit in memory when multiplied by concurrent requests?

Comment: I didn't suggest database because of this memory problems. But customer wants this. I think they will spend more money

Comment: I don't have the code I sorted out. It's around SO if you dig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Firstly **changed response type with Mono** in the client interface.

**Old code:**

```
@PostExchange("/login")
LoginClientResponse login(@RequestBody LoginClientRequest loginClientRequest);
```

**New code:**

```
@PostExchange("/login")
Mono<LoginClientResponse> login(@RequestBody LoginClientRequest loginClientRequest);
```

I also had to change service too. We should use **doOnSuccess** or **doOrNext** and must **subscribe** this process.

**Old service:**

```
final var loginClientResponse = loginClient.login(loginClientRequest);
final var token = loginClientResponse.token();
```

New Service:

```
final var loginClientResponse = loginClient.login(loginClientRequest);
    loginClientResponse.doOnSuccess(response->{
    log.info("Token is successfully retrieved for user: '{}'.", 
    loginRequest.username());
    final var token = response.token();
      //do login things..
    }).subscribe();
```

Finally I changed log filter with this code;

```
public ExchangeFilterFunction logFilter() {
      return ExchangeFilterFunction.ofRequestProcessor(clientRequest -> 
      {
          log.info("Request: {}",clientRequest.method() + " " + 
          clientRequest.url());
          return Mono.just(clientRequest);
      })
      .andThen(ExchangeFilterFunction.ofResponseProcessor(clientResponse -> 
         clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
        .doOnNext(responseBody -> 
           {
             log.info("Response Body: {}" , responseBody);
             // log request and response anywhere 
           }
       ).thenReturn(clientResponse)));
    }
```

Everything works fine.